# Increased production costs associated with increased output produced? Why do firms have prices increase with the SRAS or Supply Curve?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, supply-and-demand

In my textbook, it said (this is for SRAS and AD, but I'm also going to apply this a bit fo microeconomics.. sorry for mixing, but my question applies in both ways, I believe) **"The average price level will need to increase too, from P1 to P2, to allow firms to cover the increased production costs associated with increased volumes of output"**

[image]
In my opinion, the price does not need to increase to make up for an "increased cost associated with increased quantity supplied/output"

1. When I was doing some math regarding all of this I realized that for a firm to "cover its cost" (maintain the same amount of profit as before) it could actually lower prices and then maintain the same amount of profit (due to the increase in quantity counteracting my hypothesized lowering of prices)

**Here is my math, which has allowed me to come to this conclusion:**
A firm sells 10 tomatoes for ¥10. Revenue is (¥10x10) = ¥100. Each tomato costs ¥5, so I do (¥5x10) to get ¥50 as a cost. Thus, profit is ¥100-¥50= ¥50. Farmer wants to maintain his profit of ¥50.... let's say now he increases his quantity supplied or output to 20 tomatoes. the cost is now (¥5x10)x2 = ¥100 (I did x2 cuz its 20 tomatoes now). For the farmer to maintain profit of ¥50 he prices the 20 tomatoes at ¥7.50 (less than previous price of ¥10), so that Revenue(¥7.50x20=¥150) and Cost(¥5x10x2=$100). Thus ¥150-¥100 is ¥50 for profit. profit maintained, but price was lowered to ¥7.50

I know I'm wrong, but I'm not able to understand the logic behind this. If anyone could help me with my specific questions or direct me to any online resources, that would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> this is for SRAS and AD, but I'm also going to apply this a bit fo microeconomics.. sorry for mixing, but my question applies in both ways, I believe

You are applying market equilibrium logic to the supply function. When aggregate demand shifts for some reason while the supply function is unchanged the equilibrium price will change.

If the short-run aggregate supply (SRAS) function is upward sloping then there are no economies of scale (in the short-run). This does not give you detailed information on what *a* firm is able to do long term.

Comment: Some of my assumptions are wrong, but I am still confused why a price increase (from an AD shift right or microeconimically a Demand shift right) is necessary if the company can maintain profits without doing so and in fact lower prices.

Comment: @Rey "*If the short-run aggregate supply (SRAS) function is upward sloping then there are no economies of scale (in the short-run).*" Perhaps you have picked a cost function $C(y) = F + cy$ where there are economies of scale and thus the figure does not apply. If you wish, edit your numerical example into your question, but also include what SRAS looks like given your cost function and AD.

Comment: I just mentioned the economies of scale out of the top of my mind. The math I am referring to is that "if  for a firm to 'cover its cost' (maintain the same amount of profit as before) it could actually lower prices and then maintain the same amount of profit (due to the increase in quantity counteracting my hypothesized lowering of prices)". Please ignore my economies of scale talking-point.

Comment: @Rey "*for a firm to 'cover its cost' (maintain the same amount of profit as before) it could actually lower prices and then maintain the same amount of profit*" This is usually not the cause. Yes, if the firm lowers the price, the quantity demanded will grow, but why would it grow in just such a way that profits stay constant? Do you have numbers or a proof to back up this claim?

Comment: @Rey As a side note: in models with supply curves firms are assumed to be price takers, they do not set their price.

Comment: A firm sells 10 tomatoes for ¥10. Revenue is (¥10*10) = ¥100. Each tomato costs ¥5, so I do (¥5*10) to get  ¥50 as a cost. Thus, profit is ¥100-¥50= ¥50. Farmer wants to maintain his profit of ¥50.... let's say now he increases his quantity supplied or output to 20 tomatoes. the cost is now  (¥5*10)*2 = ¥100 (I did *2 cuz its 20 tomatoes now). For the farmer to maintain profit of ¥50 he prices the 20 tomatoes at ¥7.50 (less than previous price of ¥10), so that Revenue(¥7.50*20=¥150)  and Cost(¥5*10*2=$100). Thus ¥150-¥100 is ¥50 for profit. profit maintained, but price was lowered to ¥7.50

Comment: pretend the ¥ is 'USD' instead. For me, writing '$' messes up the comment formatting. I've done HS Economics over the past 1.5 years and I've gotten rusty with my fundamentals, so I hope you'll understand why my economic logic and math is not the best

Comment: 1. **Edit additional information into the question, do not post it in comments.**

Comment: 2. "*he prices the 20 tomatoes at ¥7.50 (less than previous price of ¥10), so that Revenue(¥7.50*20=¥150*" If the farmer has complete freedom of pricing and can always sell the given quantity at any price, why not sell 1 tomato for ¥1million? (Or a million tomatoes for ¥6.) That way he can make way more money!

Comment: 3. Do you know what market equilibrium is, and what the demand function has to do with it?

Comment: Response to #1: Ok,done. Response to #2: I'm just following the positive linear relationship of the supply curve. I'm not trying to go too far into anything hypothetical, but rather just graphically and mathematically seeing if "a high price is justified due to the additional costs associated with increased quantity supplied or output". Response to #3: I do know it, but perhaps my foundational understanding is not fully correct. Do you have any online resources that will fully lay it out for me or if I have a smaller issue, can you please point out what I'm not doing correctly with my logic?

Comment: @Rey I am going to make this my final response. (This is going on too long.) Firms in this model do not set the price, the market does. Even if firms did set the price, they cannot sell arbitrary quantitites at price $p$, the market will only buy the quantity determined by the demand function. Therefore saying that "*he prices the 20 tomatoes at ¥7.5*" is a non-sequitur. This is not something he can trivially do. There are many resources talking about market equilibrium, any good micro textbook will do, e.g., Varian's Intermediate Microeconomics.

Comment: Understood. I think I have a better understanding now (I had been confusing market equilibrium with the supply curve and I should not mix the two the way I did) and I will also additionally go back and review my fundamentals. Thank you for your time and patience throughout this entire ordeal.